# Getting some NA values using left_join dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting NA values for only some rows in my first table (doses) when I am using dplyr::left_join, but these rows have correspondent values in my second table (grid). I wrote a small example below:

```
set.seed(1234)
x_s <- c(1.0, 0.6, 0.2)
y_s <- c(0, 0.5, 1.0)
doses <- data.frame(x = x_s, y = y_s)
doses

y <- seq(0, 1, length = 3)
x <- seq(0, 1, length = 6)
prob <- runif(length(x))
grid <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
grid$prob = prob
grid 

left_join(doses, grid, by = c("x", "y"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Error in runif(nrow(x)) : invalid arguments`.

Comment: Looks like you're implicitly using equality testing on floats and running into  precision problems. See the classic FAQ [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061)

Comment: `doses[2,1] == grid[10,1] && doses[2,2] == grid[10,2]` will demonstrate that.

Comment: If you multiply your `x_s` and `y_s` by 10 (and define your sequences as `seq(0, 10, ...)`) everything is fine.